when i try get value cell current selection row give me previous value of cell
i created InterActive Datagrid and it's colum currencyId create dynamicAction event execute JavaScript query and set this code
// Get the Interactive Grid model
var model = apex.region("PAYEMNTDetails").widget().interactiveGrid("getViews", "grid").model;

// Retrieve the selected rows
var selectedRecords = model.getSelectedRecords();

if (selectedRecords && selectedRecords.length > 0) {
    // Access the first selected record
    var record = selectedRecords[0];
    
    // Get the CurrencyId field value
    var currencyId = record[3]; // Replace 3 with the actual index of CurrencyId field, or:
    // var currencyId = record.getValue("CURRENCYID"); // If the field name is "CURRENCYID"
    
    console.log("CurrencyId:", currencyId);
} else {
    console.log("No row is selected.");
}


i want to get the current value after changed
the problem : this code give me previous value before change

the cause was because region don't refresh after change. I used the following code before my code
apex.region("PAYEMNTDetails").widget().interactiveGrid("getViews", "grid").refresh();


Changes do only get effective into the model upon 'tab' (focusout). So this is after the DA on change.
You can get the changed value from the columnitem though. Another option is to use the model change notification instead of DA.

I had never used this Dtagrid, but what you are writing seems like an issue with update after change. E.g. try to request data with some time offset
setTimeout(() => { /* get your data here */}, 1000))

If you get the correct value with this, then it is obvious you have to find out when to actually request data (some 'update' event from the grid, for example).
Also, I found two similar questions answered:
Refresh selected rows in IG
Select IG rows after refresh

Thanks for the answer
although i used other method but your answer drew my attention to the real cause of the problem .
thanks Bro

Great to hear that :)
